# Middle Eastern Atmos

Tags: field-recording, ambience, atmosphere, location-recording

Heading to Saudi Arabia later this week for a doc. Should have several days off in which I plan to do as much field recording as possible. Any thoughts regarding what to record/specific requests?

Answer (score 4):

Such a great opportunity! I encourage you to record the everyday hustle and bustle of life…you probably won't need to travel too far to find really interesting material. Try settling in somewhere for a couple of hours; once people forget you are standing around with a microphone they will return to their normal behaviors, much like nature recording.

And please consider posting your treasure trove so we can all enjoy it! Be safe -

Comment: Good advice, Jay. And absolutely, I plan on uploading the keepers upon my return. Cheers!


Answer (score 3):

Desert ambiences and open-air markets spring to mind. I have a friend who grew up there; let me ask her what else to go after.

Addendum: @Rob - She says,

"We went to a small city called Al-Khobar all the time to go shopping, and there's some hustle & bustle of cars, buses, people walking & talking, etc. Except for the language, though, it's
not much different from other cities. That is, until prayer time. Almost
all mosques have speakers that broadcast the prayer calls outside so that
folks can pray wherever they are. That's pretty cool. You can't miss it
because all the stores close for about 15 minutes.

My favorite place was Hofuf, which was a small village near an old fort,
and it had a couple of markets, including the camel market and the folks
who make pottery. The camel market is full of great sounds, as you can imagine. I'm sure there
are several in the kingdom."

Comment: How do you record desert ambiences, I lived in Dubai but currently in NZ and when I went with my brother on a photography adventure with my gear last year it was dead silent, which was great cause I could get some good recordings of our car there, I never thought that I  would ever duck and almost scream after hearing a bird fly in my life, it sounded so loud there haha.

Answer (score 1):

The call to prayer would be interesting!